# JFrame size change unintentionally during runtime

Tags: java, swing

I'm working on a complex java swing project.
during initialization I set the frame size to 1280X1024.
sometimes when I launch my app the frame starts with the expected dimensions
other times the frame actual size is 1282X1053 (always this size).

I have two question, while trying to pinpoint the source for this issue.

1) is there a way to set a watch point when the frame size is changed?
I'm using eclipse, and when I tried to set a watch point, it breaks when every component I have changes size. this is unacceptable as I have too many components to manually follow.

2) due to the fact that the issue doesn't reproduce every time, I'm worried that maybe somewhere in the code I access Java swing component outside the EDT. is there a way to verify that all the calls to all the swing components in my code are done from the EDT?

EDIT:
the below code is a sample of what I use.
I can't attach the code to build the panels as it is too complex to fit here

EDIT 2: the code below works. the problem is happens because of the commented lines before calling setVisible

```
package com.earlysense.nursestation;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class MyFrame extends JFrame {

    private JPanel west;
    private JPanel center;

    /**
     * Initializes the panels
     */
    public void init() {

        setLocation(0, 0);
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1280, 1024));
        setUndecorated(true); // The frame is fixed. It cannot be moved or resized.
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JPanel p = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        west = new JPanel();
        west.add(new JLabel("west"));
        center = new JPanel();
        center.add(new JLabel("center"));
        p.add(BorderLayout.WEST, west);
        p.add(BorderLayout.CENTER, center);
        getContentPane().add(p);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    MyFrame frame = new MyFrame();
                    frame.init();
                    frame.pack();
                    // at this point frame.getSize() returns 1280X1024
                    // add components to west and center panel which depends on the frame size to set self size
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                    // at this point frame.getSize() sometimes returns 1282X1053
                }
            });
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {/* Do nothing */

        } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: _"is there a way to verify that all the calls to all the swing components in my code are done from the EDT?"_  -[`SWingUtilities.isEventDispatchThread()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html#isEventDispatchThread%28%29)

Comment: this question isn't insteresting somehow, there woudln't be needed to test for EDT at application startup, more see [see Initial Thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html), it must be used there...., note to avoids hardcoding for set(Xxx)Size, then JFrame.pack() must returs (everytime and forever) the desired Rectangle

Comment: Can you add the code that you are using for setting the size of the JFrame.

Comment: @peeskillet that is a way to verify that a single call is done from the EDT. I can find all the calls to swing components in my code, so wrapping each call with this check is not an option.

Comment: Im looking at your MCVE and I'm not really understanding the question at hand. What is the exact problem I should be looking for with this program?

Comment: @peeskillet I edited my question to make it clearer, the code snippet works. I can not attach the full code that cause the problem/ my problem is that after calling setVisible(true) the frame size changes. I'm asking for a tool/method that will allow me to find the  cause for this. or for explanation as to something I'm doing wrong that can cause it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like a bug in java.
was known in java 1.3, but apparently still happens. I'm using ubuntu 13.10 64bit, jdk: OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.12.6) (6b27-1.12.6-1ubuntu2.1)
[link](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=4424690)

Answer (score -1):

> I set the frame size to 1280X1024.

Why? My screen is 1024 x 768, so I guess I can't use your application? Don't hardcode values. Instead use:

```
frame.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
```

> SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait(new Runnable() {

Why are you using invokdeAndWait? All the Swing tutorial and suggestions by people in the forum use `invokeLater(..)`.